# Highcharts, ROR basic visualisation of table data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, highcharts

I am trying to get a bar chart to show data from a table. The table is called notes and I want to be able to show the total notes created by users on each day over a period of time. A basic chart.

I followed the railscast tutorial on this.

The chart interacts with the data but I get crazy numbers.

```
<script>
 $(function() {
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: "notes_chart",
      type: "column"
    },
    title: {
      text: "Notes by Day"
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: "datetime"
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "Notes",
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat("%B %e, %Y", this.x) + ':' +
         "Number of Notes:" + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0);
      }
    },
    series: [{
      pointInterval: <%= 1.day * 1000 %>,
      pointStart: <%= 9.weeks.ago.to_i * 1000 %>,
      data: <%= (9.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Note.created_at(date)}.inspect %>
    }]
  });
 });
 </script>
```

Note.rb

```
def self.created_at(date)  
    where("date(created_at) = ?",date).sum(:created_at) 
    end
```

The y axis show the number of notes in 1,000's (don't know why). When I create a new note it shows I have created 2,000 and something notes. I just want it to show how many notes were created on such a date.

Would appreciate any guidance. Perhaps I am going about it totally the wrong way with the created_at column?

Here is my table

```
<table class="table table-striped border table-bordered table-hover success panel-body" id="datatable">


  <thead>
    <tr class="tableheaders danger">
      <th>Created at</th>
      <th>Updated at</th>
      <th>Teacher ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :email) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :Student_Alias) %></th>
      <th><%= sort_link(@q, :subject_type) %></th>
      <th>Grievance</th>
      <th>Penalty</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @notes.each do |note| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= note.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= note.updated_at.localtime %></td>
        <td><%= note.user_id %></td>
        <td><%= note.user.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= note.user.email %></td>
        <td><%= note.studentname %></td>
        <td><%= note.subject_type %></td>
        <td><%= note.grievance %></td>
        <td><%= note.penalty %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', note, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %></td>

          <% if note.user==current_user %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_note_path(note), class: 'btn btn-info btn-xs' %></td>
          <% end %>
          <% if current_user.admin %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', note, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' %></td>
          <% end %>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Image:

[image: Image of chart]

I just want to create a simple bar or line chart that shows the number of notes on each day over a given period. Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not rails-man, but why do you use `pointInterval`+`pointStart`, while later you use ` Note.created_at(date)`? If you could show `data: [...]` you get in the browser, that would me help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean the table? Or the log from the command line? I have provided an image from the browser above and you can see what the tool tip shows and the y axis numbers. I just followed the tutorial.

Comment: I mean source page of the website. You know, generated JS ;)

Comment: series: [{
      pointInterval: 86400000,
      pointStart: 1440425947000,
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 20151023145910.0, 0, 120906150842409.0, 0] This? If not how do I get that on Edge?

Comment: That's what I wanted to see. You see, your ruby code generates: `20151023145910.0` - is that what you wanted to see in the chart? One value = `20151023145910.0`? It looks like 2015-10-23 with value: 145910.0 which was merged in rails as one value, which seems wrong.

Comment: Hi, no I just want to see the date and the correct number of records generated. For example the above is just one record. I just want it to show the date and the "Number of Notes" as 1 (or 2 etc). Here is what is in created_at in the record: 2015-10-25 23:05:27 +0000.

Comment: Hi, for getting number of notes on each day is only possible when you set your `x-axis` with week days. In current scenario, you can get the number of notes in a given period of time that is `week`.

Comment: Thanks very much. Happy new year. Might tackle this tomorrow. Never fixed it. Cheers.